# Create a directory within a local git repo

Tags: git

I have cloned a repo on my local PC, and I wish to create a directory structure within the local repo.

Do I just create a directory, then push the change back to the remote, or is there a specific process?

Comment: Git doesn't track directories – only files (and their paths).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 5):

Git does not track directories; it will just implicitly create a directory when you create a file inside the directory. If you want to commit an empty directory, the convention is to create a file named `.gitkeep` inside it.

Then just `git add` that file, `git commit` and `git push` as normal.